# GUI Extensions | Editor extensions improvement

Tags: 2011, 2013, gui-extensions

While developing a GUI extension, So far the Live documentations and few google searches helped a lot to impl,ement the same. Also referred the HelloWorld Basic example here: http://www.julianwraith.com/2010/10/helloworld-extension-for-tridion-2011/

However, I'm unable to find references for selectors/queries/ like:
$config.expandEditorPath()
$popup.create
$models
$const

I have Downloaded the GUI Extension API .

Are these $config a kind of CLASS (may be totally wrong I Am ) in Anguilla ? as expandEditorPath() seems kind of a function. Where is this class $config  is Documented so that I can check for other useful functions of this $config .

What are these dollar variables $config, $models etc..

Comment: As an additional tip: I usually "check for other useful functions" by just typing in the class in the JavaScript console of my choice (F12 usually). You'll get code-completion there. Note that you'll usually have to choose the correct frame first, but you'll learn the right one soon enough :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these are aliases pointing to oft-used classes. They should be listed under "global" in the GUI Extension API documentation.

Here's a list of the ones I use most often, for your convenience:

```
$commands = Tridion.Core.CommandManager
$config = Tridion.Core.Configuration
$controls = Tridion.ControlRegistry
$display = Tridion.DisplayController
$evt = Tridion.EventRegister
$localization = Tridion.Utils.Localization
$log = Tridion.Core.MessageLog
$models = Tridion.ModelsFacade
$assert = Tridion.Utils.Assert
$const = Tridion.Constants
$dom = Tridion.Utils.Dom
$xml = Tridion.Utils.Xml
$popup / $popupManager = Tridion.Controls.PopupManager
```

Comment: Awesome. My sincere thanks and appreciation to you for sharing this info. And yes, got the Alias list in global too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The official Gui Extension API documentation can be downloaded from [SDL docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF)

Comment: already downloaded this but unable to locate what I am looking for. Can you please help me locate the HTML/XML file which explains $config ??